# PHP - get all XML child nodes of a specific type

Tags: php, xml, parent-child, nodes

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child name='Child1' />
        <child name='Child2' />
        <subparent>
            <child name='Child3' />
        </subparent>
    </parent>
    <child name='Child4' />
<root>
```

Using PHP `simplexml` I am trying o get all the '*child*' nodes, no matter what level, and I would like to know if there's a quick function for that, instead of scanning each node of the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is use an [`xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) query on your XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml);

foreach( $xml->xpath( '//child') as $child) { 
    $attributes = $child->attributes();
    echo $attributes['name'] . "\n";
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/TrDJW) that this prints:

```
Child1 
Child2 
Child3 
Child4
```